# Are there differences between the node packages installed by different versions of npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

There are 2 versions of node.js - LTS and latest current version. When using `npm install` to install packages, are the packages installed independent of the node.js being used? Do different node.js versions install different versions of the packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they don't. When you install a npm package, it has its own version but of course package's version and node's version affect the usability of these packages.So, you need to delete old version of node from your system files. One more thing, please do not install npm packages global.Because when you do  that, next time maybe you can use it in a other project but when it is updated by creater, you won't be able to have new updates and features or as I said before it can't be compatible with the new version of node.